# Are all these functions surjections?

Tags: functions

For Z x Z to Z where (integers).

```
F(x,y) = 2x - y
F(x,y) = x^2 - y^2
F(x,y) = x^2 - 4
```

My answer is that all three ARE indeed surjections and have inputs, but i cannot find a way to formally prove this. If they werent, then i would find a counterexample, but that doesnt work here.

Can someone explain how to prove them?
Thanks

Edit: Does this proof sort of seem in the right direction for 2x - y?:

```
-let z be in the set of integers
-let x = 1/2 and y = 0
-f(x,y) = z
-So proof holds
```

And for the second one:

```
-Let z be in set of integers
-let x = z and y = 0
-F(x,y) = z
-Proof holds
```

Comment: For the first, if you specify a value $a$ then $F(0,-a)=a$, so you're good.  A hint for the second:  $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$  See if you can use that to get desired values.  You shouldn't need a hint for the last one.

Comment: Can the third function take the value $F (x,y)=-5 $?

Comment: Hmm seems not. Can you check my edit for the proof and see if it's correct? And how can you find that F(x,y) doesn't hold without finding a counterexample?

Comment: I don't understand the arguments you give, post edit.  For the first, you can't take $x=\frac 12$...this is just a function on the integers.  For the second, $F(z,0)=z^2$, not $z$.

Comment: Ahh you're right. The second one is not a surjective function

Comment: How to prove that though?

Answer (score 2):

**Claim:** $F(x,y) = 2x - y$ is surjective.

**Proof:** For any $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $F(0,-z)=z$

**Claim:** $F(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$ is not surjective.

**Proof:**
Note that $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ is the product of two factors whose difference is $2y$. In other words these factors are either both odd or both even. Their product then must be either odd or divisible by $4$. This implies that any number that is equivalent to $2$ mod $4$ cannot be represented as difference of two squares and is not in the range of this function.

**Claim:** $F(x,y) = x^2 - 4$ is not surjective.

**Proof:** $x^2\geq 0 \Rightarrow x^2-4 \geq -4$

In other words $-5$ is not in the range neither is any integer less than $-5$.